# This app is incompatible with your device in play store(Galaxy S5, Only READ_PHONE_STATE Permission)

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I just developed a simple widget "SIM Info Widget", which shows very basic information like SIM State, Serial Number, Operator Name etc.

For any of the information just I need an Instance of TelephonyManager and  "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" permission.

When I directly run the app in my Phone(Samsung Galaxy S5/G900I) through Eclipse, it got installed and running perfectly.(Screenshot is attached)

But when I published it in Google Play, It says This app is incompatible with your device

The Manifest is

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ragini.siminfowidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver
        android:label="Detials of SIM"
        android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
            <action         android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_basics" />
            </receiver>



   </application>

  </manifest>
```

Can any body please suggest me why it is happening, Because my phone supports Cellular Activities like Calling, SMS etc, Still the problem occurs.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I have similiar problem tried everything I found on the web, but nothing helps yet.

Comment: No countries restrictions? Nothing in Google Play developer console?